# Android findViewById Working Sometimes

Tags: android, null

I am having a very weird glitch that I cannot get my head around. Any help will be appreciated as this works on a phone running Android 2.3, tablet running 3.1 but not on a phone running Android 2.1.

I am trying to get the LinearLayout defined in the following XML with the ID of "overview_linear_layout".

**overview_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <include layout="@layout/listing_view" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/header_view" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></include>
    <ScrollView android:id="@+id/scrollView1" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/overview_linear_layout">
            <TextView android:scrollbars="vertical" android:longClickable="false" android:layout_weight="1" android:clickable="false" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/main_description"></TextView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <include layout="@layout/listing_view" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/footer_view" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="0.0"></include>

</LinearLayout>
```

The code I am using to get the view is as follows:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.overview_view);
    LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.overview_linear_layout);

    if(linearLayout!=null) {
        System.out.println("Found linear layout");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Did not find linear layout");
    }
}
```

I have tried Project->Clean in Eclipse but that does not help either.

Comment: post your import statement.

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.overview_linear_layout);
```

to

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.layout.overview_linear_layout);`
```

Answer (score 0):

if eclipse don't show overview_linear_layout when you type click on the red cross and click create constant overview_linear_layout in R .